# Javascript handle display issues with Dates

Tags: javascript

Web developers often use JavaScript for common tasks on their websites. In this tutorial we'll show you the top 10 JavaScript snippets you can use on your webpages by just cutting and pasting!
In this article we're going to cover the following popular script snippets!

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var now = new Date();

var days = new Array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');

var months = new Array('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');

var date = ((now.getDate()<10) ? "0" : "")+ now.getDate();

function fourdigits(number) {
    return (number < 1000) ? number + 1900 : number;
                                }
today =  days[now.getDay()] + ", " +
         months[now.getMonth()] + " " +
         date + ", " +
         (fourdigits(now.getYear())) ;

document.write(today);
</script>
```

Comment: Don't deface posts, even ones you created.

Answer (score 1):

In both functions, you would need to calculate next location, so I would separate this into a function:

```
applyInstuction : Char -> Location -> Location
applyInstuction instruction loc =
    case instruction of
        '>' ->
            { loc | x = loc.x + 1 }

        '^' ->
            { loc | y = loc.y + 1 }

        '<' ->
            { loc | x = loc.x - 1 }

        'v' ->
            { loc | y = loc.y - 1 }

        _ ->
            loc
```

Basically, it takes a location and based on instruction computes the next location.

### calculateFinalLocation

Then `calculateFinalLocation` can be implemented like:

```
calculateFinalLocation : Location -> String -> Location
calculateFinalLocation { x, y } instructions =
    List.foldl applyInstuction { x = 0, y = 0 } <| String.toList instructions
```

If you are not familiar with `foldl` (there is also `foldr`) - you can check it out, for example, here: https://www.brianthicks.com/guide/functional-sets/4-and-a-half/. It's similar to `map-reduce` in JavaScript.

### calculateFirstIntersection

Next we can implement `calculateFirstIntersection` using `Set` (http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Set). Set will store locations, which we already visited.
Here is the code:

```
calculateFirstIntersection : String -> Maybe Location
calculateFirstIntersection instructions =
    .result <|
        List.foldl
            (\instruction { visited, loc, result } ->
                case result of
                    Nothing ->
                        let
                            nextVisited =
                                Set.insert ( loc.x, loc.y ) visited

                            nextLoc =
                                applyInstuction instruction loc
                        in
                            if Set.member ( loc.x, loc.y ) visited then
                                { visited = nextVisited
                                , loc = nextLoc
                                , result = Just loc
                                }
                            else
                                { visited = nextVisited
                                , loc = nextLoc
                                , result = Nothing
                                }

                    _ ->
                        { visited = visited
                        , loc = loc
                        , result = result
                        }
            )
            { visited = Set.empty, loc = { x = 0, y = 0 }, result = Nothing }
        <|
            String.toList instructions
```

Here in `foldl` function, we using `{ visited, loc, result }` because we need to know not just a new location, as in `calculateFinalLocation`, but also already visited locations and a result (did we already found an intersection?). I've used a lambda function here, but you can move it to a regular function if you wish.

Here is the live code example of it: https://ellie-app.com/MDbmPFsjvwa1